# How to use swipe in appium javaclient 7.0?

Tags: java, appium

I'm using appium `java client 7.0` and i do realize `driver.swipe()` was depreciated
I tried out `Touchactions` & using `Javascript executer`, seems like it doesn’t work either

Can someone tell how to swipe the screen (if you have already tried out in 7.0 and if any method works for anyone)?

Comment: you can try this, the solution for 6.x i'm not sure it will work for 7.0 or not:  http://ezyautomation.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-perform-vertical-and-horizontal.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TouchAction` class to do swipe action now.
Check swipe image gallery horizontally example:

```java
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
...
        AndroidElement gallery = driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/gallery");
        List<MobileElement> images = gallery
                .findElementsByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");
        int originalImageCount = images.size();
        Point location = gallery.getLocation();
        Point center = gallery.getCenter();

        TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(element(images.get(2),-10, center.y - location.y))
                .waitAction(waitOptions(ofSeconds(2)))
                .moveTo(element(gallery,10,center.y - location.y))
                .release();
        swipe.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Touch Actions method support from java client 6.1.0 onward

```
 TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
        ta.press(PointOption.point(207, 582)).moveTo(PointOption.point(8, 
        -360)).release().perform();
```

you need to specify the x and y coordinates from where to where you need to scroll
i hope this works for you because this works for me